# React js & node js problem connecting to database sqlite

Tags: reactjs, node.js, sqlite

I want to connect my database with component in React js but it didn't work

I try to connect with different ways, but it didn't work so can someone to figure out how it works or some solution because i used the AI but nothing happens.

so this my project in more further :

first of i will creat an component that contains a screen

and second is Upload component that contains :

four fields :

Button whene i can choose either video or image

After i need to upload the image from my local PC

and third is input to change the name of image or video

and after that a button to upload the image or video

and Third component is displaying component that helps me to choose the screen and generate path that is contain the contents that i upload on the second component

and all the files(images/videos) Linked to sqlite db

```
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();

const upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' });

const app = express();

// Improved error handling
const handleError = (err, res) => {
  console.error(err);
  res.status(500).send(err.message || 'Internal server error');
};

// Store database path in environment variable
const dbPath = process.env.DB_PATH || '../Database/displayscreen.db';

// Connection pool for efficient database access
const pool = new sqlite3.Database.Pool(dbPath);

app.post('/upload', upload.single('file'), async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const filename = req.file.filename;
    const filetype = req.body.filetype;
    const filepath = `uploads/${filepath}`;

    // Sanitize user input (not shown here)

    // Establish database connection from pool
    const db = await pool.promise();

    // Prepare and execute SQL statement
    const stmt = await db.prepare('INSERT INTO displayscreen (filename, filetype, filepath) VALUES (?, ?, ?)');
    await stmt.run(filename, filetype, filepath);

    res.status(200).send('Upload successful');
  } catch (err) {
    handleError(err, res);
  } finally {
    // Release connection back to pool
    await db.close();
  }
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server listening on port 3000');
});
```

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios'; // Assuming you're using axios for API calls

const UploadComponent = () => {
  const [mediaType, setMediaType] = useState('video');
  const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState(null);
  const [fileName, setFileName] = useState('');
  const [uploadStatus, setUploadStatus] = useState(null);
  const [uploadError, setUploadError] = useState(null);

  const handleUpload = async () => {
    setUploadStatus('Uploading...');
    setUploadError(null);

    try {
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('file', selectedFile);
      formData.append('mediaType', mediaType);

      const response = await axios.post('/upload', formData, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        },
      });

      setUploadStatus('Upload successful!');
      setSelectedFile(null); // Clear selected file input
      setFileName(''); // Clear filename input

      // Optionally, handle response data from server here
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Upload error:', error);
      setUploadStatus(null);
      setUploadError('Upload failed. Please try again.');
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <select value={mediaType} onChange={(e) => setMediaType(e.target.value)}>
        <option value="video">Video</option>
        <option value="image">Image</option>
      </select>
      <input type="file" onChange={(e) => setSelectedFile(e.target.files[0])} />
      <input type="text" value={fileName} onChange={(e) => setFileName(e.target.value)} />
      <button onClick={handleUpload}>Upload</button>
      {uploadStatus && <p>{uploadStatus}</p>}
      {uploadError && <p className="error">{uploadError}</p>}
    </div>
  );
};
```